# Cannot build plugin example

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to build [the plugin example](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/test/run-pass-fulldeps/auxiliary/roman_numerals.rs) from the book but it won't work:

```
rustc failed to resolve: could not find `quote` in `ext`
```

What am I supposed to do? The example does not even have any build instructions. Is this on purpose?

Comment: Which version of rust are you using ? it compiles with `rust roman_numerals.rs` using `rustc 1.32.0-nightly`

Comment: Maybe I got it, your link to [github-repo](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/test/run-pass-fulldeps/auxiliary/roman_numerals.rs), and [code in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/plugin.html#syntax-extensions) is different. try the code in github.

Comment: And the code in github says that `This code also appears in src/doc/unstable-book/src/language-features/plugin.md. Please keep the two copies in sync!  FIXME: have rustdoc read this file`, but not yet sync'ed until now.

Comment: @ymonad Yes, I used the code from the book. Using the code from the github repo instead of the code from the book made it compile. Thank you very much. I was stuck on this for days.

Comment: Glad that you solved the problem. maybe I should post it as answer for someone who might stuck in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [code in the unstable book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/plugin.html#syntax-extensions) and [code in current source of rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/test/run-pass-fulldeps/auxiliary/roman_numerals.rs) is different.

In the code, it says that:

> This code also appears in src/doc/unstable-book/src/language-features/plugin.md.
>
> Please keep the two copies in sync!  FIXME: have rustdoc read this file

But seems not yet fixed until now.

Your error occurs from `use syntax::ext::quote::rt::Span;` in the unstable book, which should currently be `use syntax_pos::Span;`

Since the book is for unstable features in rust, and according to [top page of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/the-unstable-book.html),

> Because this documentation relates to unstable features, we make no guarantees that what is contained here is accurate or up to date. It's developed on a best-effort basis. Each page will have a link to its tracking issue with the latest developments; you might want to check those as well.

Therefore, there might be similar problem in other code of the book.

Comment: Thanks for getting me unstuck. I learn from this. You may check in my repo if you like https://www.gitlab.com/montao/forbasilers